# Как убрать ограничение размера SVG объекта от размытия?

Tags: svg, blur, svg-filter

Есть размытый SVG объект, но если его размыть достадочно сильно, что-то не даёт ему размываться дальше, и обрезает часть.

```css
.circle{
    fill: #0adaf5;
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="svg">
 <defs>
  <filter id="blurCircle">
   <feGaussianBlur id="blur" in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50"/>
  </filter>
 </defs>
 <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" class="circle" filter="url(#blurCircle)">
  <animate
    id="blurAnimation"
    attributeName="r"
    values="50; 100; 50"
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="remove"
  />
 </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: я же сказал уже, маску сделать тому объекту который размыт

Comment: Ладно, создан маску с path глаза и применить её к фильтру

Comment: Ну задай id всему svg и так и пиши begin="svg.onmouseover" а финишем будет end="svg.onmouseout"

Comment: Ты меняешь темы вопроса на лету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно это повтор вот этого вопроса - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555600/gaussian-blur-cutoff-at-edges
Там предлагают увеличить размеры самого фильтра (его холст).

Comment: Потому что там увеличивается холст (рендер таргет в видеокарте), на котором рисуется эффект, а не круг увеличивается.

Comment: я действительно увидел разницу ..спасибо - понял в чём плюс такого решения